# Make parcer at colab for learning images

Tags: google-colaboratory, argparse

i hope to make parcer at colab but somethig wrong

**here is my code**

```py
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
from urllib.request import urlopen
import argparse
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root_dir = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/img/"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='input.')
parser.add_argument("-name", "--people", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
people = args.people

def main():
    url_info = "https://www.google.co.kr/search?"
    params = {
        "q" : people,
        "tbm":"isch"
    }
    html_object = req.get(url_info,params)

    if html_object.status_code == 200:
        bs_object = BeautifulSoup(html_object.text,"html.parser")
        root_dir = bs_object.find_all("img")

        for i in enumerate(root_dir[1:]):
            t = urlopen(i[1].attrs['src']).read()
            filename = "byeongwoo_"+str(i[0]+1)+'.jpg'
            with open(filename,"wb") as f:
                f.write(t)
            print("Img Save Success")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**and this is error message**

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -name PEOPLE
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -name/--people
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2890: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Comment: Looks like you are running this a jupyter-notebook. Commandline arguments (and argparse) cannot be used in notebooks (or at least it's hard). Arguments provided to the jupyter launcher are for that, not the notebook. Use interactive tools in the notebook to provide arguments like this.

Comment: thank hpaulj, it running on colab.